# Sprinter Browser returns None

Tags: python, python-3.x, splinter

I am trying to build a simple splinter application in python but I am getting a Type when calling visit(). Browser apparently returns None. I use python 3.10.6 and splinter 0.18.1.

Note this example is directly taken from https://splinter.readthedocs.io/en/latest/. Other browsers get the same error.

```
from splinter import Browser
browser = Browser('firefox')
browser.visit('http://google.com')
```

"TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not callable"

Comment: `Browser()` does not return None, or the error would have been `AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'visit'`

Comment: In any case, please update the question to include the whole error traceback message.  Otherwise we are guessing where the error happened.